# Duplicate entry for index with FactoryGirl when running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl to create a "Specialty" model that has a unique index on the `code` column.

When I create multiple factories of the "Specialty" model I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: Factory(:specialty)
Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry 'AN00' for key 'index_specialties_on_code': INSERT INTO `specialties` (`code`, `name`) VALUES ('AN00', 'Name')
Duplicate entry 'AN00' for key 'index_specialties_on_code'
```

What's the right way to deal with this? How come the index associated with the model is not blown away with the model. I am using DatabaseCleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a sequence for your factories:

```
Factory.sequence :code do |n|
  "AAA#{n}"
end
```

And at your specialty factory use the sequence:

```
Factory.define :specialty do |f|
  f.code { Factory.next(:code) }
  # other assignments here
end
```

This way you will always have new codes.

Comment: I have a certain number of specialties. It's quite likely that no more will be added to the database. Should I put the stuff in a seeds.rb? If so then how would I use factory girl to associate unique specialties to prevent the same mysql error?